Svelte key block {#key var} stops working after focusing on another browser tab
I noticed that using the key block in svelte to toggle a re-render of a component inside the block will stop working if I visit another tab for some minutes. I know that the browser stops processes of the webpage that is not being used right now, but is the key block also affected by it?
PS: the var passed to the key block is a boolean
I expected the key block working flawlessly, but changes on var did not affect anything to the key block. I managed to get the key block working again by clicking on another browser tab and back to my project. After that, changes to the var got registered by the key block

I use opera browser and I just tried to re-create the same effect on chrome and it works just fine there.

If you switch from your website's tab and the web browser then decides to idle your tab, the JS code in it will stop running, but it should resume running again when you switch back to the tab, and none of this should effect Svelte/SvelteKit/key blocks at all. If you have scheduled things (like setTimeout() or setInterval()), they might be affected, but I can't imagine seeing what you are describing. Can you show the relevant code for it?

 {#key state}    <Avatar userId={$userStore.id} username={$userStore?.username} class="w-[200px] sm:col-start-2 border-2 border-surface-500" draggable="false" /> {/key} it is just a normal avatar component which shows the user's avatar. After the user uploads a new avatar, I switch the bool value in state, and it re-renders the component that forces the browser to get the new avatar from s3 (through cache headers). I think it is a problem how opera stops the js code and reactivate it and I cant fix it myself

the problem might be that Opera caches the image/ takes long time to fetch the image? In the #key block, I think you can use <p>{Math.random()}</p> to see when it's re-rendered (you should get a new number each time), and see if the problem is that it's not re-rendered, or if the problem is connected to Opera not fetching the picture.
